# SPFx files will be replaced on app update

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx

i'm creating an spfx app and now i have a problem.

When i bundle my app i got the following files:

- .sppkg file
- (manifest-id).json
- the "main" .js file
- a locale .js file

Now i updated the app and bundled it again.
Because i changed some things the files got new names (i think a hash at the end of the files).
But the .json file had the same name.

Now i uploaded the files (not the .sppkg) into my cdn. But then i was wondering why the new functions i implemented are available directly without updating my app on my website content.

But then i realized that i replaced the .json file on my cdn, because the name of this file was the same. But the new file referenced to the new .js files.

My question is how to avoid that this happens?
Is this calculated by microsoft, but then the whole "update process" makes no sense.

And i don't what to change the id on the "MyAppWebbPart-Manifest.json" file everytime (this id is the name of the .json file).

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. There is no standard way to have multiple versions of the same solution available side by side. Assets are hashed so that when new version of the package is deployed, all clients use corresponding assets instead of the previously downloaded and cached ones.